# Case-insensitive sort in C

Tags: algorithm, c, homework, quick-sort

I wrote a sorting program so that if the optional argument `-i` is present then the sorting should be done without taking into account lowercase / uppercase letters.

The program uses the standard library `qsort()` algorithm; case-insensitive option is handled by `getopt()` if the `-i` flag is supplied to the program.

Please criticize my implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* simple comparison function
   just plain string compare from standard library
   qsort passes to this a pointer to a member of the to be sorted array
   this member is a string, so a cast is needed to double pointer
*/
int simple_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}

int insensitive_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcasecmp(*(const char **)a, *(const char **)b);
}

/* natural comparison function
   contrary to the other required sorting methods, standard library does not
   have a function for this (actually there is one for directory contents,
   but it is a specialized function not dedicated to string comparison)
   it acts as a normal comparison as long as there is no digits to compare
   when both strings have digits as the next character, instead of comparing
   them, turn it into a number (all the consecutive digits) and compare that
   number as if it was a single character
*/
int natural_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *stra = *(const char **)a;
    const char *strb = *(const char **)b;

    while (*stra && *strb)
    {
        if (((*stra < '0') || (*stra > '9')) ||
            ((*strb < '0') || (*strb > '9')))
        {
            if (*stra < *strb)
                return -1;
            else if (*stra > *strb)
                return 1;
            stra++;
            strb++;
        }
        else
        {
            long long na;
            long long nb;
            char *end;
            na = strtoll(stra, &end, 10);
            stra = end;
            nb = strtoll(strb, &end, 10);
            strb = end;
            if (na < nb)
                return -1;
            if (na > nb)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    if (*stra != 0)
        return 1;
    if (*strb != 0)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i, iFlag = 0, nFlag = 0, rFlag = 0, nrFlaguri = 0;
    int opt;
    int (*sort_func)(const void *, const void *) = simple_cmp;

    /* getopt will cycle through the parameters searching for optional arguments
       if the specified argument is found store the required configuration
       one cannot parse normal arguments until getopt finished cycling through
       all the arguments
       getopt will rearrange the parameter list, so all positional arguments
       are moved to the end, hence normal processing can be done only after
       all optional arguments are consumed
       if unknonw options are detected exit the program with an error message
       as it is most likely a user error or typo and should be corrected
       to achieve expected results
    */
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nri")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'n':
        nrFlaguri++;
        nFlag = 1;    
                sort_func = natural_cmp;
                break;
        case 'r':
        nrFlaguri++;
        rFlag = 1;
        break;
        case 'i':
        nrFlaguri++;
        iFlag = 1;
        sort_func = insensitive_cmp;
        break;
            default: /* '?' */
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    
    if(argc == optind)
    {
    printf("Only optional parameters have been entered");
    return 0;
    }

    if(nrFlaguri > 1)
    {
    printf("Only one sorting option can be selected");
    return 0;
    }

    /* after rearranging the arguments, optind is updated to reflect the
       starting position of the first non-optional argument
       all parameter processing after getopt finished should start from optind
       instead of 1
    */

    /* quick-sort as implemented in the standard library
       it sorts in-place a given vector of unspecified type elements
       the size of a single element, and the length of vector must be supplied
       along the vector itself
       additionally a comparison function must be specified which can compare
       individual elements of the vector
    */
    qsort(&argv[optind], argc-optind, sizeof(char *), sort_func);
    if (rFlag == 1) {
    for(i=argc-1;i>=optind;i--)
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    }
    else {
    /* displaying sorted parameters one by one */
    for(i=optind;i<argc;i++)
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice work delegating `simple_cmp` and `insensitive_cmp` in a way that is compliant.

Answer (score 1):

**Bug: String handling is *unsigned***

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).  C17dr § 7.24.1.3

Below compares incorrectly<sup>*1</sup><sup>*2</sup> when `*stra` and `*strb` signs differ.

```
const char *stra = *(const char **)a;
const char *strb = *(const char **)b;
   ...
        if (*stra < *strb)
```

Instead as below.

```
const unsigned char *stra = *(const unsigned char **)a;
const unsigned char *strb = *(const unsigned char **)b;
```

Other code may also need changing.

Note that `if (*stra != 0) return 1;` *assumes* `*stra > 0`.

**Why `long long`?**

With `na = strtoll(stra, &end, 10);`, rather than use `long long`, consider `intmax_t` for the longest well supported signed integer type.  Today, this might be the same, but plan for tomorrow.

**Define when needed**

```
        // long long na;
        // ...
        // na = strtoll(stra, &end, 10);

        long long na = strtoll(stra, &end, 10);
```

**Sign-less?**

`if (((*stra < '0') || (*stra > '9')) || ((*strb < '0') || (*strb > '9')))` prevents integer compare should the number begin with a sign `'+'` or `'-'` or white-space.

I'd either allow integers to begin with a sign or use `unsigned long long na = strtoull(stra, &end, 10)` for additional range.

Further: If staying with positive base ten, consider comparing digits as text, then there is no real upper integer size bound.

**Only base 10?**

Consider `strtoll(stra, &end, 0);` instead of `strtoll(stra, &end, 10);`.

**Not a standard C solution**

Neither `#include <unistd.h>`, `strcasecmp()` nor `getopt()` are part of the standard C library.  If coding to a specific implementation, best to tag the question as such.

**Use an auto-formatter**

Below betrays manual formatting.  Increase productivity and uniformity - use an auto-formatter.

```
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 'n':
    nrFlaguri++;
    nFlag = 1;    
            sort_func = natural_cmp;
            break;
    case 'r':
    nrFlaguri++;
    rFlag = 1;
    break;
```

---

<sup>*1</sup> Compliant `strcmp()` behaves as if the characters were *unsigned*, even if `char` is *signed*.

<sup>*2</sup> There also exist an issue is a *signed* `char` is using non-2's complement that is solved correctly with `unsigned char *`.  But those encodings are rare these days.